# Two sections in html form and how do I create dashboard using only html5 and css3?

Tags: html, css

I'm new to HTML/CSS so I need your help people. I have created a page with form on left side and I want one dashboard to be displayed on the right side, I'm trying to do this but not getting. Tell me how to solve this.

**Service V1.html**

```
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="section1">
<form class="cbp-mc-form">
<fieldset class="scheduler-border">
<legend class="scheduler-border">Service</legend>
<div class="cbp-mc-column">
    <label for="number">Number</label>
        <input type="text" id="number" name="number" placeholder="575">
        <label for="client">Client</label>
        <select id="client" name="client">
            <option>Choose a Client</option>
            <option>C1</option>
            <option>C2</option>
            <option>C3</option>
        </select>
        <label for="name">Name</label>
        <input type="text" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Kumar">
        <label for="email">Email Address</label>
        <input type="text" id="email" name="email" placeholder="kumar@name.com">
        <label for="category">Category</label>
        <select id="category" name="category">
            <option>Choose a Category</option>
            <option>C1</option>
            <option>C2</option>
            <option>C3</option>
        </select>
        <label for="description">Description</label>
        <textarea id="description" name="description"></textarea>
        <label for="creation_date">Date of creation</label>
        <input type="text" id="creation_date" name="creation_date" placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY">
        <label for="end_date">End Date</label>
        <input type="text" id="end_date" name="end_date" placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY">
    </div>    
    <div class="cbp-mc-column">
    <label for="attachment">Attachment</label>
        <input type="file" id="attachment" multiple="multiple" name="attachment">
    <label for="title">Title</label>
    <input type="text" id="title" name="title" placeholder="">
    <label for="comment">Comment</label>
    <textarea id="comment" name="comment"></textarea>
    <input class="cbp-sm-submit" type="submit" value="Select All" />
    <input class="cbp-sm-submit" type="submit" value="Remove" />
    <input class="cbp-sm-submit" type="submit" value="Add Item" />
    <input class="cbp-sm-submit" type="submit" value="Download" />
    <label for="select_files">Select files</label>
    <select id="select_files" name="select_files" multiple="multiple" style="height:206px">
    </select>
</div>
<div class="cbp-mc-submit-wrap">
<input class="cbp-mc-submit" type="submit" value="Submit" />
<input class="cbp-mc-submit" type="submit" value="Cancel" />
<input class="cbp-mc-submit" type="reset" value="Clear" />
</div>
</fieldset>
</form>
</div>
<div class="section2">
Section 2 will come here.
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Style.css**

```
#wrapper {
width: 1400px;
background-color: #FFF;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
}
#section1 {
float: left;
width:650px;
}
#section2 {
float: right;
width: 750px;
}
fieldset.scheduler-border {
    border: none;
    box-shadow:  5px 5px 25px #CCCCCC;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
legend.scheduler-border {
    background: #10689a;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 5px 10px ;
    font-size: 22px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px #CCC;
    border-radius:2px;
    margin-left: 20px;
}
.cbp-mc-form {
    position: relative;
}
.cbp-mc-form:before, 
.cbp-mc-form:after { 
    content: " "; display: table; 
}
.cbp-mc-form:after { 
    clear: both; 
}
.cbp-mc-column {
    width: 40%;
    padding: 10px 10px;
    float: left;
}
.cbp-mc-form label {
    font-weight:bold;
    display: block;
    padding: 10px 5px 5px 2px;
    font-size: 0.8em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    cursor:pointer;
}
.cbp-mc-form input,
.cbp-mc-form textarea
{
    font-family: 'Lato', Calibri, Arial, sans-serif;
    line-height: 1.5;
    font-size: 1em;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    color: #000;
    display: block;
    width: 230px;
    background: transparent;
}
.cbp-mc-form select 
{
    font-family: 'Lato', Calibri, Arial, sans-serif;
    line-height: 1.5;
    font-size: 1em;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    color: #000;
    display: block;
    width: 252px;
    background: transparent;
}
.cbp-mc-form input,
.cbp-mc-form textarea,
.cbp-mc-form select {
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
    box-shadow:3px 3px 10px #F2F2F2;
}
.cbp-mc-form textarea {
    min-height: 60px;
    min-width:230px;
}
.cbp-mc-form input:focus,
.cbp-mc-form select:focus,
.cbp-mc-form textarea:focus,
.cbp-mc-form label:active + input,
.cbp-mc-form label:active + textarea {
    outline: none;
    border: 1px solid #0099FF;
}
.cbp-mc-form select:focus {
    outline: none;
}
::-webkit-input-placeholder { /* WebKit browsers */
    color: #10689a;
    font-style: italic;
}
:-moz-placeholder { /* Mozilla Firefox 4 to 18 */
    color: #10689a;
    font-style: italic;
}
::-moz-placeholder { /* Mozilla Firefox 19+ */
    color: #10689a;
    font-style: italic;
}
:-ms-input-placeholder { /* Internet Explorer 10+ */
    color: #10689a;
    font-style: italic;
}
.cbp-mc-submit-wrap {
    text-align: center;
    padding-top:40px;
    padding-left:210px;
    clear: both;
}
.cbp-mc-form input.cbp-mc-submit {
background: #10689a;
border: none;
color: #fff;
width: auto;
cursor: pointer;
text-transform: uppercase;
display: inline-block;
padding: 5px 20px;
font-size: 1em;
border-radius: 2px;
letter-spacing: 1px;
}
.cbp-mc-form input.cbp-mc-submit:hover {
    background: #1478b1;
}
.cbp-mc-form input.cbp-mc-submit:active
{
transition: all .1s linear;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 0 #003333;
    transform: translateY(7px);
}
.cbp-mc-form input.cbp-sm-submit
{
    background: #0099FF;
    color:#FFF;
    border:none;
    border-radius:5px;
    margin-top:10px;
    display:inline-block;
    padding:5px;
    width:100px;
    text-align:center;
    cursor:pointer;
    font-size:1em;
}
.cbp-mc-form input.cbp-sm-submit:hover {
    background: #00CCFF;
    border-radius:5px;
}
.cbp-mc-form input.cbp-sm-submit:active{
    border:none;
}
```

Comment: Looks fine, so what is your question? You currently have a placeholder where the right content should go. Looks like that placeholder is positioned correctly. So go!

Comment: I want to make two sections in same page i.e, In one section form will come and in another section dashboard has to come.

Comment: Yes, you wrote that before. So? Do it. _What is your question?_

Comment: It is unclear what you ask. You create a static html page. In there you have two "sections". The sections are placed next to each other just as you want it. One section contains your form, all fine. The other section contains a placeholder you put there. So I would say all you have to do is replace the placeholder with whatever content you want to place in there. That is trivial. That is why I ask: _what is your question?_

Comment: How do I create dashboard?

Comment: i send for you answers,in it i say how create dashboard and add menu to it.

Answer (score 0):

your code Working correctly!

you just add your dashboard  code on `<div class="section2">...</div>` for example like this

```
<div class="section2">
   <fieldset class="scheduler-border">
      <legend class="scheduler-border">dashboard</legend>
         <div class="cbp-mc-column">
            this is dashboard
         </div>
    </fieldset>
</div>
```

**Image**

[image: Html]

and now for example you can add menu here in dashboard

```
<div class="section2">
    <fieldset class="scheduler-border">
        <legend class="scheduler-border">dashboard</legend>
        <div class="cbp-mc-column">
          My Dashboard
          <ul class="vert-one">
             <li><a href="#" title="CSS Menus" class="current">Home</a></li>
             <li><a href="#" title="CSS Menus">Articles</a></li>
             <li><a href="#" title="CSS Menus">Topics</a></li>
             <li><a href="#" title="CSS Menus">Forum</a></li>
             <li><a href="#" title="CSS Menus">Blog</a></li>
             <li><a href="#" title="CSS Menus">Subscribe</a></li>
             <li><a href="#" title="CSS Menus">Contact Us</a></li>
          </ul> 
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</div>
```

&

```
ul.vert-one{margin:0;padding:0;list-style-type:none;display:block;
font:bold 16px Helvetica, Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;line-height:165%;
width:200px;}

ul.vert-one li{margin:0;padding:0;border-top:1px solid cdcdcd;
border-bottom:1px solid 676767;}

ul.vert-one li a{display:block;text-decoration:none;color:#000;padding:0 0 0 20px;width:180px;}

ul.vert-one li a:hover{
background:#00CCFF url("images/vert-one_arrow.gif") no-repeat 0 9px;}

ul.vert-one li a.current,ul.vert-one li a.current:hover{
background:#10689A url("images/vert-one_arrow.gif") no-repeat 0 9px;}
```

**Image**

[image: menu]

---

for change dashboard to right change the css code to

```
#wrapper {
width: 1400px;
background-color: #FFF;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
}
#section1 {
float: right;
width:650px;
}
#section2 {
float: left;
width: 750px;
}
```

full code here http://cssdeck.com/labs/collab/x34ywhga

Comment: What is this? Is this really meant to be an answer? It only repeats what I wrote in the comments 10 minutes earlier, and the code you give is trivial. There is no content in this "answer". So what are you trying to show here?

Comment: **(⊙▂⊙)** I don't see your comments when i open Questions no comments here and I went to see what the problem is, It seems you very severe upset if you want delete Answer

Comment: I am certainly not upset! Why should I be? I just asked what it is you want to show here. Your answer does not give any new information, it does not change anything! So how is it meant to answer the question?

Comment: And it's not reducing width also.

Comment: i add change dashboard to right in Answers

Comment: @MAK ok i add your width to css `wrapper -> 1400px` , `section1 -> 650px` , `section2 -> 750px`

Answer (score 0):

I note in your code that your `.section2` overlap the `form` note it setting a `background-color` to your `.section2`, to fix it you can use one of the follow ideas.

**1-** Float left the `form` and set margin to `.section2`:

```css
*{
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.left-form {
    padding: 40px 10px;
    margin: 0;
    float: left;
    width: 250px;
    background: #44aac1;
}

.section2 {
    height: 300px;
    background: #ddd;
    margin-left: 250px;
}
```

```html
<form class="left-form">
  <input type="text" value"some text"/>
  <button>submit</button>
</form>


<div class="section2" id="content">
    Section 2 will come here.
</div>
```

**2-** Floating both elements and set width to `.section2`:

```css
*{
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.left-form {
    padding: 40px 10px;
    margin: 0;
    float: left;
    width: 250px;
    background: #44aac1;
}

.section2 {
    float: left; /*or right*/
    height: 300px;
    background: #ddd;
    width: calc(100% - 250px);
}
```

```html
<form class="left-form">
  <input type="text" value"some text"/>
  <button>submit</button>
</form>


<div class="section2" id="content">
    Section 2 will come here.
</div>
```

Comment: You really think that is an answer to the OPs question? I'd say that should be a comment, since it is only a small detail. I suspect the OP has a completely different question in mind...

Comment: @arkascha I edit the answer to clarify what the OP is doing wrong.

Comment: As said: I doubt that is the real issue the OP has... but we will see, maybe the OP will answer to my comments above...

Comment: True, the question is not clear enough, mainly because the OP almost gets what he wants (not quite right) but the OP say "I want dashboard to be displayed on the right side, I'm trying to do this but not getting" so I answer how to display  the .section2 on the right side in the right way.